# adding id to unordered list in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

i've created a **view** with all the recent node titles and **styled** them as an **HTML unordered list** ..
it generates the list but, the **ul** tag doesn't have an **id** :(
how can i add that?
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make your own template instead of the one that views use. There you can alter the markup. Chech the "theming information" link inside the view itself for info on what to call it. Place it in your theme and remember to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

to expand on what googletorp said, you'll find the original template files in the 'theme' sub-directory. it's easiest to copy that into your theme directory and edit it, rather than starting from scratch.